# virtualizing nested containers (virtualizingstackpanel) to a single parent scrollbar in WPF

Tags: wpf, virtualization, virtualizingstackpanel

I've kind of coded myself into a pickle on this one.  I am writing a custom WPF control which is similar to the `TreeListView`  described in [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771523.aspx)  as well as many other places on the net.  A pretty big pile of this thing is custom at this point, and it's meeting my goals fairly well, except on the virtualization front.  My overriden `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` templates both use `VirtualizingStackPanel`s to present their items, and I've verified that all of this is getting created as expected.  The virtualization works correctly on root level items (only the UI elements for those currently visible in the `ScrollViewer` are cooked up), and the `TreeView` stuff takes care of not generating the elements for collapsed nodes.  The problem comes when expanding a node -- all the elements are cooked up for every child in the node, even the thousands that are offscreen.

It seemed to me like all I needed to do was somehow set the scrollowner property of the inner nested `VirtualizingStackPanel`s to the same main scrollview that the root level VSP gets hooked up to by default, but I read an MSFT poster [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0f94bb14-7d5e-4d10-bd38-1ddecf8d7237) saying that this will not work.

Unfortunately this thing is slow as mud without the virtualization occurring, so I need to come up with some sort of solution.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but do you recall what you did to get around this?

Comment: I just realized that [David's account has been inactive for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17784/david-hay?post-filters=All&post-sorts=Newest). So for anyone coming along after me, [see my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42842476/3063273)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but was still relevant for me.

In my case I thought a `TreeView` wouldn't cut it because I need exactly two layers, and the types of items displayed are different between the two layers. Also, I'm refactoring a list of `Expander`s so I was thinking more one-dimensionally.

But then I realized that you can customize the `ItemTemplate` of the `TreeView` to include your own `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, and that you can customize the `ItemTemplate` of that `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with your own tailored `DataTemplate`... Presto! Exactly two layers with different things in each!

So my point is that the `TreeView` is flexible enough that you should try not to create your own custom control.

Here's what I did:

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Foo.Views.TreePage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo.Views"
      xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Foo.ViewModels"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Tree page"
      d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:TreeModel}">
    <TreeView
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"><!-- IList<Person> -->
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate><!-- Template for first layer, which has a HierarchicalDataTemplate so that this layer will expand -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                ItemsSource="{Binding Expenses}"><!-- IList<Expense> -->
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate><!-- Template for the second layer, which has a DataTemplate instead of HierarchicalDataTemplate so that this layer won't expand -->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}"/><!-- Expense amount in dollars -->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/><!-- Person name -->
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Page>
```

The `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

The `Expense` class:

```
public class Expense
{
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of the above code in action]

I inspected it with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to prove that it is UI Virtualizing. Here's the number of loaded `TreeViewItem`s when the app is small:

[image: Screenshot showing the number of elements when the app is small]

...And here's the number of loaded `TreeViewItem`s when the app is fullscreen (it keeps going beyond this snippet, but you get the idea):

[image: Screenshot showing that there are more elements when the app is fullscreen]

Now it's just the simple matter of styling things to make the nested layer look how I want!

Edit: I just verified that the `TreeView` virtualizes all its layers, not just the first layer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a link to a list of what not to do with a virtualizing stackpanel, but for some reason the page comes up blank.  Here's another page that talks a little about it:

http://www.designerwpf.com/2008/02/12/listview-and-listbox-performance-issues/

and even links to the one im talking about, but its always blank.  if you look on that page its the link to Mark Shurmer's blog.  Here's the link if you'd like to try it:

http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/wpf/listview-is-it-really-too-slow/

Bea Stollnitz also has some articles on it that might help:

[Part 1](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=42)
[Part 2](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=43)
[Part 3](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=45)

If you post some of your code, someone might be able to unravel the spaghetti a bit to help you get to a better implementation.

EDIT: Found a link that might work (thank you archive.org!!!):
http://web.archive.org/web/20080104163725/http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/wpf/listview-is-it-really-too-slow/